# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: InputFileProgressEvent

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I have application developed using JSF, IceFaces and deployed inside Tomcat but when I tried to start tomcat, I am getting below exception.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.GlassFishConfigureListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: InputFileProgressEvent
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2547)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1410)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ManagedBeanFactoryImpl.getMethodsWithAnnotation(ManagedBeanFactoryImpl.java:1164)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ManagedBeanFactoryImpl.<init>(ManagedBeanFactoryImpl.java:188)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:1201)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:772)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:529)
        at com.sun.faces.config.GlassFishConfigureListener.contextInitialized(GlassFishConfigureListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: InputFileProgressEvent
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        ... 24 more
May 1, 2015 7:41:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 1, 2015 7:41:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

Please help me to trace out the issue.

Comment: Why do you still not tell about the versions used as commented in your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986273/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-icefaces-x-context-bridgefacescontext2 Don't you realize how important that information is?

Comment: I am using icefaces.jar of version 1.8.2_7  and jsf-api-1.2.jar of version 1.2.